# Create .env file from a .json file

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, env-file

.env files are used to store environment variables in a certain project. I am looking to be able to easily programmatically modify an .env file, and in that case using JSON (a .json file) would be much easier as far as I can tell.

Say I had file like so env.json:

```
{
  "use_shell_version": true,
  "verbosityLevel":3,
  "color": "yellow"
}
```

is there a good way to export those? Is there some .env file format that is easily modified by machines instead of by hand?

Comment: There are various libs that parse `.env`, such as this one which can [return an Object representation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config)

Comment: Your mean is change env.json to .env ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the purpose of actually making a .env file out of a .json file ? I still cannot understand why would you like to do so, or what compels you to do so ?

Comment: I'm looking for such a solution, too.

In my case, I have a JSON file that's used as a key for an API, and I want to save it as as `.env` variable.

I know how to do it, I'm just looking for a tool that does it.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert a JSON file to .env with a simple for loop.

```
function convertToEnv (object) {
    let envFile = ''
    for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
        envFile += `${key}=${object[key]}\n`
    }
    return envFile
}
```

So the with your example object given,

```
const object = {
  "use_shell_version": true,
  "verbosityLevel":3,
  "color": "yellow"
}

const env = convertToEnv(object)

console.log(env)
```

output would be

```
use_shell_version=true 
verbosityLevel=3 
color=yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonData = {
    "name": "Miri",
    "surname": "Hasanov",
    "age": 30,
    "test": {
        "test1": "test1",
        "test2": {
            "test2": "test2"
        }
    }
};

function flattenObject(obj, parentKey = '') {
    let result = {};

    for (const key in obj) {
        const currentKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}_${key}` : key;
        const value = obj[key];

        if (Object.isExtensible(value) && typeof value === 'object') {
            Object.assign(result, flattenObject(value, currentKey));
        } else {
            // For return
            result[currentKey.toUpperCase()] = value;

            // For set process
            // proccess.env[currentKey.toUpperCase()] = value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(flattenObject(jsonData));
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense as an answer as env files are just key=value, and I don't see a case where one would have nested env properties in json.